# How do I save multiple selected tracks as separate files?

Tags: audacity

I have a bunch of tracks in an Audacity project, a few of which I would like to export. However, I want each track to reside in its own audio file.

**Export Multiple** will (as far as I can tell) split the tracks, but will export every track in my project.

**Export Selected Audio** will export only those tracks which I have selected, but will combine them into one audio file.

Comment: If they are raw recordings then maybe you could copy them from your hard drive, from wherever they reside.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is not a "Export Multiple" that only exports the selected tracks.

You can always of course delete the audio files that you don't want after the export operation, but if you're trying to avoid that, e.g. to save export time or the required disk space, there is a workaround that may suit you.

Save your project under a different name (to preserve the original) and in the new project just delete the tracks you don't want to export.

You can create as many copies of your project as you want (even by copying the project file in Windows Explorer) and apply different changes (e.g. deleting tracks) to each copy. This will not change the original project file, nor the source or saved audio files within the project.

Answer (score 0):

Mute the tracks you don't want to export.